# KeyError - Don't understand why

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Trying to get the count of all payment method instances:

```
    def paymentMethod(self):
        # Stores unique payment methods as dictionary keys with count of times used as values
        myDict = {}
        keyList = list(self.df['Institution'].unique())

        for i in keyList:
            count = self.df.groupby(i).count()
            myDict.update(i, count)

        print(myDict)
```

Here's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 40, in <module>
    x.paymentMethod()
  File "final.py", line 29, in paymentMethod
    count = self.df.groupby(i).count()
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6515, in groupby
    return DataFrameGroupBy(
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 525, in __init__
    grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 786, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'Chase Checking'
```

I don't really understand what the error is trying to tell me?  Sorry if this is a nooby question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupby` groups on **column names**. Your dataframe doesn't have a column named `'Chase Checking'`.

You seem to look for this:

```
def paymentMethod(self):
    # Stores unique payment methods as dictionary keys with count of times used as values
    myDict = self.df['Institution'].value_counts().to_dict()

    print(myDict)
```

Answer (score -1):

The KeyError is for the column `Chase Checking`

You can generate the count map using `Counter` from `collections`

```
from collections import Counter

def paymentMethod(self):
    count_map = Counter(self.df['Institution'])

    return count_map
```